# Merging AppDelegate_iPhone and AppDelegate_iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

I have got an old Xcode project. I am not sure how old. But I see two AppDelegate classes. I think this is created using Xcode 3:

> ```
>    AppDelegate_iPhone and AppDelegate_iPad
> ```

What I want to do is to have one AppDelegate class instead (it's what usual now). For this, I have created a subclass of UIResponder, which also conforms to the UIApplicationDelegate protocol. Then in main.m, I return the following:

> ```
>    UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
> ```

I expected that now the AppDelegate class would be the main app delegate for the application. However this is not happening. I still see the control going to AppDelegate_iPhone class (when I run the code for an iPhone).

Comment: Could you please post what was inside the main.m before your edited it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but if you haven't written anything on your AppDelegate_iPhone and AppDelegate_iPad you can try to delete both of them, create a new project and copy the AppDelegate that gets created on the project you want, then on main.m import the newly created AppDelegate:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

Comment: Creating a new project is not an option. Is there any other option?

Comment: You misunderstood me,you need to create a new project just to have both AppDelegate.h and AppDelegate.m files, then you export both of these files on your old project and on your main.m you import the new AppDelegate

Comment: Oh..Okay..let me try that and get back :)

Comment: Hopefully it works :) But as Geet said Xcode has changed a lot since 3.0 so it might give you some errors

Comment: Hi Signo, Copying the Appdelegate did not work. But what did work was also your idea :) I deleted the existing app delegates (the separate ones). Now it takes my new appdelegate as the actual application delegate.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you create a new Project entirely and then just Import all the files related,whereas for APpdelegate-iPhone or AppDelegate_iPad, just combine their code and distinguish between iPhone and iPad using USerInterfaceIdiom…..Xcode has changed a lot since 3.0, you would never know where you may lose reference of one file or another

Comment: Creating a new project is not an option. Is there any other option?

Comment: not that I know of…but I still think merging them may help